# jQuery click event only triggered in console

Tags: jquery

I have a simple example for testing:

```
<input id="test" type="text">
<input id="ts" type="submit">
```

I want to use jQuery to alert when the submit button with the id "ts" is pressed.

```
$('#ts').on("click", function() {
   alert(1)
});
```

But nothing is happening. Where when I do the exact same thing in the Javascript console of chrome, everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put this at the load event of the document as above:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#ts').on("click", function() {
     alert(1)
   });
});
```

Comment: Wow.. thank you! I never thought about that. Works fine!